# NSDate not working properly

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

i want to get the current every second but when i implement the concept the time is not changing in NSTimer my code is

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer *timer){
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSString *dateTime = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"Date and Time :%@",dateTime);
}];
```

and my output is [image] to which the time is also wrong.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `NSDateFormatter`. The format specifiers in your code are all wrong. Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a mistake when you try to set the date format with:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];
```

I tried it with:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```

and my output is:

```
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:50 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:51 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:52 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:53 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:54 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:55 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:56 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:57 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:58 PM Central European Standard Time
Date and Time :Jan 27, 2017, 8:05:59 PM Central European Standard Time
```

Maybe this site can help you to set up your `dateFormat`: http://nsdateformatter.com

When you set up the following format (with small `mm` and `ss`):

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

You see the correct minute and second

```
Date and Time :2017-01-27 20:10:18
Date and Time :2017-01-27 20:10:19
Date and Time :2017-01-27 20:10:20
Date and Time :2017-01-27 20:10:21
Date and Time :2017-01-27 20:10:22
```

Comment: The format is still wrong. It needs to be: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.